# How could I remove elements from the list based on other property values?

Tags: java, java-stream

Assuming I have a Person class and a list to track the status updates.
I only need the TODO status to be displayed. I tried with removeIf but think that would not be right here.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    int id;
    String name;
    String status;
}
```

```
public class PersonHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person(1, "Jon", "TODO");
        Person p2 = new Person(2, "Doe", "TODO");
        Person p3 = new Person(3, "Jon", "DONE");
        Person p4 = new Person(4, "Jane", "TODO");
        Person p5 = new Person(5, "Doe", "DONE");

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(p1);
        persons.add(p2);
        persons.add(p3);
        persons.add(p4);
        persons.add(p5);

        persons.removeIf(p -> p.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
        persons.forEach(p -> {
            System.out.println(p.getName()  +  "#" + p.getStatus());
        });
    }
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
Jon#TODO
Doe#TODO
Jane#TODO
```

But Jon and Doe were updated to DONE. But since Jane status is still TODO as there were no DONE updates yet for Jane, the expected output is:

```
Jane#TODO
```

Comment: Do you expect those `Person` objects with the same name to somehow collapse into each other when you `add`?

Comment: I would remove the keyword eventually. If this is a list I fetch from a table or create manually. What I want is when I query this source I should output only the TODOs with no DONEs.

Comment: That's exactly what you have. All those `Person` objects remaining have `TODO`, eg `Jon#TODO`.

Comment: @Savior Jon#TODO was when he is id:1 now he was "Jon", "DONE" at id:3. I am not interested in listing him on the UI anymore. So I would remove him from the result list.

Comment: Elements in your list are unique... You need to use `HashSet<Person>` and implement `equals` and `hashCode` for "same name" to be removed.

Comment: Those two objects are completely unrelated. That's what I meant by _collapse_. You'll need to handle "merging" them together. Java won't do that for you. (All this before you do your `removeIf`.)

Comment: **But Jon and Doe were updated to DONE.** - where they were updated?

Comment: If source data suffered updates you just needed to re-filter or re-removeif the collection again. I would suggest edit your question in order to clarify it. If you want the data to be filtered as soon as an update happens in your data, you might think about implementing a pattern like Observer.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri on the UI that would list all TODOs I will have a button action to run some backend logic and update them to DONE. It is like a queue structure to list TODO items with a DONE button across and expect the queue to only list TODOs not DONEs.

Comment: You should use a `filter` on a UI, not remove elements from the list... Unless that is the expected action

Comment: @OneCricketeer Reason is in the same UI page there is a option to see all DONE items. Also queue TODOs are done by different user groups who are not bothered about DONEs.

Comment: Anyways, question still makes it unclear how "updates" are happening. If you have UI issues, perhaps you could edit question to include a [mcve] of that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can accomplish it. First, stream over all the people and group together the entries by the person's name. Then take the final entry for each person (`list -> list.get(list.size() - 1)`). If a person was TODO, then went to IN_PROGRESS, then became DONE, we want to throw away those first two.

This will give us a `Map<String, Person>` which is a map from the person's name to their last entry. We don't really care about the map, it is just a stepping stone to get us where we want to go. We can just take the `values()`, and iterate over them.

Now we can filter out the entries which are done, and `collect` what's left.

```
List<Person> notDone = persons.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getName,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> list.get(list.size() - 1))
        )
    )           // here we have a Map<String, Person>
    .values()   // then a Set<Person>
    .stream()   // then a Stream<Person>
    .filter(p -> !p.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: how much would this suffer on performance if lets say I have 100K persons to stream and do this mapping to list.

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode The answer to all performance questions is: profile it and see. The only measurement which matters is whether something is *fast enough*. Whether it's fast enough for your particular application is only something you can answer.